# What is cordova/argscheck used for?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

I am trying to figure out what does cordova/argscheck do. I was not able to find any documentation that describes what is it used for nor how to use it.

I managed to find its [git repo](https://github.com/apache/cordova-js/blob/master/src/common/argscheck.js) however no comments are mentioned in the code. I have also taken a look at a couple of plugins and they seem to use it as follows:

```
Device.prototype.getInfo = function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
    argscheck.checkArgs('fF', 'Device.getInfo', arguments);
    exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "Device", "getDeviceInfo", []);
};
```

This code has been taken from the Device plugin. Find the [git repo here](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-plugin-device.git;a=blob;f=www/device.js;h=b1d0d25d12c87b3365944c1b9475c688eb6fa779;hb=HEAD).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have figured it out is seems that the function is used to check the parameters to make sure that they are one of the following:

```
'A'=> 'Array'
'D'=> 'Date'
'N'=> 'Number'
'S'=> 'String'
'F'=> 'Function'
'O'=> 'Object'
'*'=>  'Anything goes'
```

This check is done to make sure that the java calls that will be called using the exec function will not throw any errors because of bad parameter types.

Comment: For those wanting to dive deeper, the argscheck code repo is [here] (https://github.com/apache/cordova-js/blob/master/src/common/argscheck.js). Some repositories will have something like `'sFF'`, but the `checkArgs(...)` converts everything to uppercase to then check against this list from @thedethfox.